# How can I start IPython running a script?

Tags: python, ipython

My use case is I want to initialize some functions in a file and then start up IPython with those functions defined. Is there a way to do something like this?

```
ipython --run_script=myscript.py
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html), it's trivial:

> You start IPython with the command:
>
> ```
> $ ipython [options] files
> ```
>
> If invoked with no options, it
> executes all the files listed in
> sequence and drops you into the
> interpreter while still acknowledging
> any options you may have set in your
> `ipythonrc` file. This behavior is
> different from standard Python, which
> when called as `python -i` will only
> execute one file and ignore your
> configuration setup.

So, just use `ipython myfile.py`... and there you are!-)

Comment: This answer is now out of date. See @Maarten's answer below. You need to use a `-i` flag, along with any other options you want, followed by the python script name. This way, you will be left in the interpreter rather than dropping back out immediately

Answer (score 113):

In recent versions of IPython, you do need to add the `-i` option to get into the interactive environment afterwards. Without the `-i` it just runs the code in *myfile.py* and returns to the prompt.

```
ipython -i myfile.py
```

Comment: As an additional note, "recent versions" here means after the 0.10.2 ~> 0.11 architectural revamp, and the "-i" option is backwards compatible to ipython 0.10.2 (I can confirm) and likely lower (I can speculate).

Answer (score 18):

You can use IPython profiles to define startup scripts that will run every time you start IPython. A full description of profiles, is given [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/overview.html#startup-files). You can create multiple profiles with different startup files.

Assuming you only need one profile, and always want the same startup files every time you start IPython, you can simply modify the default profile. To do this, first find out where your IPython configuration directory is in an ipython session.:

```
In [1]: import IPython
In [2]: IPython.paths.get_ipython_dir() # As of IPython v4.0
In [3]: print(ipython_config_dir)
/home/johndoe/.config/ipython
```

For this example, I am using Ubuntu Linux, and the configuration directory is in `/home/johndoe/.config/ipython`, where `johndoe` is the username.

The default_profile is in the `profile_default` subdirectory. Put any starting scripts in `profile_default/startup`. In the example here, the full path would be `/home/johndoe/.config/ipython/profile_default/startup`.

Comment: I don't know if it's a recent addition, but locating the path for a given profile is done by `IPython.paths.locate_profile()`

Answer (score 16):

Nowadays, you can use the startup folder of IPython, which is located in your home directory (C:\users\[username]\.ipython on Windows). Go into the default profile and you'll see a startup folder with a README file. Just put any Python scripts in there, or if you want IPython commands, put them in a file with an .ipy extension.

Comment: Thanks, nice to know about the startup dir. I recently found about exec_files in the config file options. Seems startup dir files are executed before exec_files entries. The link is informative.

Comment: `~/.config/ipython/profile_default/startup` on ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for IPython's *%run* magic command.

By typing in IPython:

```
%run hello_world.py
```

you'll run the *hello.py* program saved in your home directory. The functions and variables defined in that script will be accessible to you too.

Comment: The question is how to start ipython with a file, not to run a file within ipython.

Answer (score 1):

The following is for the case when you want your startup scripts to automatically be run whenever you use IPython (instead of having a script that you must specify each time you run IPython).

For recent versions (i.e., 5.1.0) of IPython, place one or more python scripts you wish to have executed in the `IPYTHON_CONFIG_DIR/profile_PROFILENAME/startup` folder.

On Linux, for example, you could put your Python startup code into a file named `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/10-mystartupstuff.py` if you want it to run when no IPython profile is specified.

Information on creating and using IPython profiles is available [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html).

Answer (score -1):

Update to [Caleb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323230/how-can-i-start-ipython-running-a-script/16044223#16044223) for Python 3.5 in [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr): I made this answer self-contained by copying relevant parts of Caleb's answer.

You can use IPython profiles to define startup scripts that will run every time you start IPython. A full description of profiles, is given [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/overview.html#startup-files). You can create multiple profiles with different startup files.

Assuming you only need one profile, and always want the same startup files every time you start IPython, you can simply modify the default profile. To do this, first find out where your IPython configuration directory is in an IPython session:

Input:

```
import IPython
ipython_config_dir = IPython.paths.get_ipython_dir()
print(ipython_cofig_dir)
```

Output:

```
/home/johndoe/.ipython
```

For this example, `johndoe` is the username.

Inside the `/.ipython` folder, the default_profile is in the `profile_default` subdirectory. Put any starting scripts in profile_default/startup. In the example here, the full path would be

```
/home/johndoe/.ipython/profile_default/startup
```

Comment: As it is this answer does not answer the question. An answer has to be fully contained in itself. I suggest to complete it.

Comment: Should I just edit @Calebs answer? with this update! or make it self contained? Thanks! Have edited it though!

Comment: I don't think you should modify Calebs answer because it considerably changes it. I would add the relevant information to make your answer to answer the question by itself. Put yourself in the position of someone that read your answer without reading Calebs's, and see what information is required for that person to follow your answer start to end. :)