# Is there an IPython equivalent to Bash's semicolon?

Tags: ipython

I use IPython as my interactive shell and I almost always run two commands at the start - something like:

```
%run helper_functions.py
data = import_data('file_with_data')
```

I would like a notation to run these two at the same time (so I could recall them with an "up" arrow from history) akin to what `echo 1 ; echo 2` does in Bash.

I am aware that I can start IPython running with a script as per *[How can I start IPython running a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323230/start-ipython-running-a-script)*.

Comment: `from file_that_runs_helper_functions_and_defines_data import data`

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon is a valid statement separator in Python, the same as the newline, so you can use it with regular commands:

```
a=5; a=a+1; print "This is a: %s" % a
```

Anyway, as [pointed out by tobias_k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31034642/is-there-an-ipython-equivalent-bashs-semicolon#comment50094093_31034772), this is not working with "run" which is a special IPython macro (see the [IPython built-in magic commands](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html)) and changes the command line interpretation. Instead of `%run helper_functions.py; data = import_data('file_with_data')`, you could use something almost equivalent:

```
__builtin__.execfile('helper_functions.py') ; data = import_data('file_with_data')
```

You don't have the trace in IPython, but still your script is executed and the variables are in your interactive namespace.

Comment: This does not seem to work. `;` must not be directly after file name, and `data` seems not to be defined afterwards.

Comment: `a = 1, b = 2` indeed does work, but the magic `%run` seems to cause problems, when I then run `%run stuff.py ; b = 3`, b is still 2.