# How can I configure IPython to issue the same "magic" commands at every startup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

I'd like to be able to use `%cd "default_dir"` and `%matplotlib` whenever I call `ipython` from my terminal. I tried writing this in a .py file in `.ipython/profile_default/startup/file.py` but it results in the following error:

```
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Unknown error in handling startup files:
  File "/Users/<name>/Dropbox/.ipython/profile_default/startup/startup.py", line 18
    %cd "~/Dropbox/"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start ipython running a script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323230/start-ipython-running-a-script)

Comment: @Harrison Please see edit; perhaps you misunderstood me, or what I am asking seems obvious to you.

Comment: Nope, it's definitely not  - at least I can't seem to find it in that question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use the magic in your startup scripts:

```
get_ipython().magic('cd ~/Dropbox')
get_ipython().magic('matplotlib')
```

Put that in the contents of your startup script and it should do the magic you need ✨✨

Comment: Can you give a short explanation of why your answer works, or link me to any useful sources? Can't seem to find anything.

Comment: I searched for something like "ipython pass variable to magic function", which turned up [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14409510/344286), which was exactly the result you wanted.

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to elaborate the Wayne's answer, but do not have enough reputation to do a comment. You can have the following in the start up script to run the required magic commands

```py
from IPython.core import getipython

getipython.get_ipython().run_line_magic("reload_ext", "autoreload")
getipython.get_ipython().run_line_magic("autoreload", "2")
```

Module reference is here [Ipython module](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.getipython.html)

To run the above start up at terminal, do this

```
ipython -i startup.py
```

Comment: Very helpful. For those searching, note that you can localize the startup script folder by typing `get_ipython().profile_dir.startup_dir`