# How to set %xmode Verbose on Jupyter notebook at launch?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to set `%xmode Verbose` to get error messages in greater detail, but since I always need it, I rather want to set it at launch.

So I tried adding it on at the bottom of my `jupyter_notebook_config.py`, but then when I launch it again, it got the following error:

> Exception while loading config file /Users/me/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

However, I also added `import os, sys, random, asyncio, argparse` at the bottom of the file, which did not lead to the error. So I feel the magic command does not work at the config file.

So is there any way to enable Verbose debug mode at default in Jupyter notebook?

---

#### Clarification

This question is about Jupyter notebook (open via `jupyter notebook`), not IPython (open via `ipython`). I found the `%xmode` command works in IPython config file (which I have actually used) and want to enable it on Jupyter notebook as well, which is my point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start ipython running a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323230/start-ipython-running-a-script)

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup`.
2. Create a file named `00-set-traceback-mode.py`.
3. Add the following lines:

   ```
   from IPython import get_ipython
   ip = get_ipython()
   ip.InteractiveTB.set_mode(mode="Verbose")
   ```

You have done.

Comment: Thanks but doesn't this only work in IPython? When I start a session on Terminal (via `ipython`), it works, but when I use a browser via `jupyter notebook`, does it still work? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It surely still works. I have tested it. Doesn't work for you?